# How do I return values to receiver stream | Spark streaming

Tags: java, apache-spark, queue, jms, spark-streaming

I have the following class:

```
public class QueueProcessor implements Runnable {
    //private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(QueueProcessor.class.getCanonicalName());
    private Session session;
    private Queue queue;
    private String queueName;
    private JSONObject jaob;


    public QueueProcessor(Session session, Queue queue, String queueName, JSONObject jaob) {
        this.queue = queue;
        this.session = session;
        this.queueName = queueName;
        this.jaob = jaob;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            customConsumer();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public synchronized void customConsumer() throws Exception {
        MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);
        try {
            while (true) {
                Message msg = consumer.receive();
                if (msg != null && msg instanceof TextMessage) {
                    TextMessage tm = (TextMessage) msg;
                    JobProcessing jobProcessing = new JobProcessing(tm, queueName, jaob);
                    String finalJson = jobProcessing.process();
                    // System.out.println("Json copied for posting: " + finalJson);
                    GlobalAsyncHttpClient.getINSTANCE().postData(finalJson);
                    msg.acknowledge();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            consumer.close();
        }
    }

}
```

Now I have around 8 queues, for which I spawn 8 threads to read each queue and process through the above class using Executors / ThreadPool.

I am using Spark streaming custom to read from a JMS queue. As per the official example the code used goes like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("JavaCustomReceiver");
            JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, new Duration(1000));


            // Create an input stream with the custom receiver on target ip:port and count the
            // words in input stream of \n delimited text (eg. generated by 'nc')
            JavaReceiverInputDStream<String> lines = ssc.receiverStream(new TibcoReceiver());
            JavaDStream<String> words = lines.flatMap(x -> Arrays.asList(SPACE.split(x)).iterator());
            JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> wordCounts = words.mapToPair(s -> new Tuple2<>(s, 1))
                    .reduceByKey((i1, i2) -> i1 + i2);

            wordCounts.print();
            ssc.start();
            ssc.awaitTermination();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The line of interest here is: 
`JavaReceiverInputDStream<String> lines = ssc.receiverStream(new TibcoReceiver());`

I want the values read in the QueueProcessor back here, but how do I do that as I am in a continuous while loop. I am not aware if there is any other design pattern I can use here. Please guide!